# Pass parameters to child component using cxComponentWrapper directive in Spartacus

Tags: angular, parent-child, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I have a wrapper component that contains child components.

I'm able to successfully call and render children components using the cxComponentWrapper initiative from the parent component.

Using this in the parent.component.ts

```
    components$: Observable<any[]> = this.componentData.data$.pipe(
      switchMap(data =>
       combineLatest(
         data.childrenList.split(' ').map(component =>
           this.cmsService.getComponentData<any>(component)
       ))
     )
   );
```

And this in the parent.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async as data">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let data of (components$ | async)  ">
            <ng-template [cxComponentWrapper]="{
              flexType: data.typeCode,
              typeCode: data.typeCode,
              uid:      data.uid
            }"
            > </ng-template>
        </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

The data for the child component is successfully looked up and rendered based off the component id provided to the cmsService.getComponentData service.

My need is that there is some data elements in the parent that I also need to make use of in the child. My question is how can I pass that data from the parent to the child.

Like in the parent I have a parentTheme attribute and totalChildren that has to be used also in the child.

I was hoping something like:

```
    <ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async as data">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let data of (components$ | async)  ">
            <ng-template 
              parentTheme="sometheme",
              totalChildren={{(components$ | async)?.length}}  
              [cxComponentWrapper]="{
               flexType: data.typeCode,
               typeCode: data.typeCode,
               uid:      data.uid
            }"
            > </ng-template>
        </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

That obviously doesn't work, but just using it as an example.
How do we go about passing parent data elements down to the child?

Answer (score 0):

great to see that you came this far with implementing the cms container component implementation and use the component wrapper. The component data that you receive from the cms page structure does not contain the actual component data, only the meta information is provided. You can however use the cmsService to receive that data additionally, using:

```
CmsService.getComponentData(uid)
```

You'd need a bit of rxjs magic to pull that together, but I trust you with that.

Just be aware that in case the data is not directly available as part of the initial page structure, this will result in one or multiple additional calls to the backend to resolve the component data. For most components the data is available as part of the page structure, however container components are typically not part of the page structure.

The good news is that the component service is smart; in case you iterate over multiple components and call `CmsService.getComponentData(uid)` multiple times, the calls are merged together to only do a single call.

Comment: Thanks for the response on this. I was able to call the child component data and get the data for that child with the method you mentioned. What I was struggling with was getting some data from the parent down to the child as well.  I ended up calling the child component directly rather than going through the the <ng-template> method. Then I used the cmsservice you mentioned to get the child data. This was I was able to pass parameters from the parent as well. Thank you for the answer and support on this!

Comment: Thanks @DivadNotleks, can you "accept" the answer we do not need to get back to this?